# Error Rendering Control (type initializer PX.Data.PXLicenseObserver threw an exception) on a ListView page in Designer mode

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to overcome this error in Designer Mode of any ASPX page,
for example, CS203100 out-of-box:

[image: PX.Data.PXLicenseObserver]

I am not sure when the error began, and not sure if this could be related to any recent Windows Update.  I am working with AcumaticaERP version 18.1.102.0048 under VS2015 on Windows 10 Enterprise. The error occurs under TargetFramework 4.5.2 and also after updating to 4.7.1.  Any help please would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into the same issue with a colleague and it turns out that Visual Studio was not running with administrative privileges. It looks like PXLicenseObserver tries to create a log file on initialization and it fails when Visual Studio is not running in Administrator mode.